# Docker not listing some Folders and files in the dockercontext

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, docker-container

I am having following structure for the asp.net core application

```
.
├── Root
├── DockerFile/
│   ├── Folder1/
│   │   ├── nuget.config
│   │   └── .csproj
│   ├── Folder2/
│   │   ├── nuget.config
│   │   └── .csproj
│   ├── Folder3/
│   │   ├── nuget.config
│   │   └── .csproj
│   └── Folder4/
│       ├── nuget.config
│       └── .csproj
└── nuget.config
```

I am trying to copy the nuget config, initially it was at the root level and the docker wasnt able to recognize that. post that I added a command in docker File

```
RUN ls -R
```

to recursively list all the folders. in that I noticed its ony listing the Folder 1,2 and 3. Its not listing the Folder4 and the contents and also in the listed folders 1,2 and 3, its only listing only the .csproj file in the docker context and not nuget.config. I can see the added nuget file in the repo and I have checked the dockeringnore and gitignore. Should I have to change the docker context to list all the files? I dont understand why its not listing the folders